# Tree Navigation - opening one list item by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, navigation

I have a tree navigation and want to have the first item open by default. I can get them all to be open by default, but not just one. Putting the 'expanded' class on the list item I want open does not work. In this example I want "Large Cap" to be toggled by default. I have also tried to trigger a click via the dom and other scripts. My JS is not very good, I am just guessing..appreciate any help.

HTML

```
<div id="listContainer">

        <ul id="expList">
            <li> 
                Large Cap
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">High Dividend Yield <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">High Dividend Yield <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dividend Appreciation <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dividend Growth <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Equity Income<span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">REIT <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ultra-Short-Term Bond<span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Short-Term Corporate Bond <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Intermediate-Term Corporate Bond <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Long-Term Corporate Bond <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Long-Term Corporate Bond 2 <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>             
             <li>
                Mid Cap
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">High Dividend Yield <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">High Dividend Yield <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dividend Appreciation <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dividend Growth <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Equity Income<span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">REIT <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ultra-Short-Term Bond<span> VHDYX</span></a></li>                                             
                </ul>
            </li>                
             <li>
                Small Cap
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">REIT <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ultra-Short-Term Bond<span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Short-Term Corporate Bond <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Intermediate-Term Corporate Bond <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Long-Term Corporate Bond <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Long-Term Corporate Bond 2 <span> VHDYX</span></a></li>       
                </ul>
            </li>            
        </ul>


    </div>
```

JS

```
function prepareList() {
$('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
.click( function(event) {
    if (this == event.target) {
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
        $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');


    }
    return false;
})
.addClass('collapsed')
.children('ul').hide();
```

CSS

```
#listContainer{
margin-top: 0px;
}

#expList ul, li {
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
cursor: pointer;
}
#expList p {
margin:0;
display:block;
}
#expList p:hover {
background-color:#121212;
}
#expList li {
line-height:140%;
text-indent:0px;
background-position: 1px 8px;
padding-left: 20px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* Collapsed state for list element */
#expList .collapsed {
background-image: url(../img/collapsed.png);
}
/* Expanded state for list element
/* NOTE: This class must be located UNDER the collapsed one */
#expList .expanded {
background-image: url(../img/expanded.png);
}
#expList {
clear: both; 
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant css as well.

Comment: posted CSS, thank you for looking

Comment: Your css isn't really doing anything to hide/show content. You could try using jquery ui's accordion: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/